# CSS shrink transition not smooth

Tags: css, transition, elementor

Can't find the reason why my CSS shrink transition is only smooth when I hover the mouse, but when it goes outside of the element it doesn't work smoothly.
I use the Elementor custom CSS tab to execute the code.

```
selector:hover .elementor-column-wrap{

-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
-ms-transform: scale(0.9);
transform: scale(0.9);
transition: transform 430ms ease-in-out;
```

[image]

Comment: please supply us with at least a gif of this transition

Comment: Done, please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

BTW for the `box-shadow` animation, consider animating pseudo-element opacity instead of the `box-shadow` itself for performance. Check this link [How to animate box-shadow with silky smooth performance](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/) or google similar keywords.

```css
div:hover {
  animation: hover-in 430ms forwards;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  animation: hover-out 430ms forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hover-out {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 40px 0px rgba(244, 44, 55, .37);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hover-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 40px 0px rgba(244, 44, 55, .37);
  }
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```

Comment: No, I'm only talking about the shrink transition when I move the mouse off the element when the element is on the way back to its initial state - the transition is not smooth.

Comment: That is exactly what my snippet does, when moving the mouse out of the yellow div, the div returns smoothly to its original size.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the transition inside `.elementor-column-wrap`

Because transition makes the smoothing effect, triggering it on the hover will only do it on the hover but not on mouse out. Adding it to the main element outside the `:hover` selector will ensure the transition is also applied when mouse out